# How to make glassfish v3.1.1 run with -Xmx256m?

Tags: glassfish, java, low-memory

I have a t1.micro amazon instance and that machine have very scarce resources. I need for the moment to run glassfish3.1.1 (due to complete JEE6 support) on those conditions. Any guidance is welcome.

Using the default configuration (-Xmx512m) jvm halts at bootstrap since the SO have only ~ 620MB of total ram.

By setting -Xmx256m the server launches but it does not open the admin console.

Any help to fix it or to manage the server by other ways is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone have similar issue, all it needs to work is to enable remote administration on glassfish.

By default it comes without admin password and only available on localhost:

Better details [here](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/enabling_remote_administration_for_glassfish)